# Cheaper to use 8" electic stovetop coil or 6" coil?

Tags: electrical, stove-top, cost-effective

I found out that my Kenmore electric stove small 6" burner is really 120v.
The larger 8" coil is 220v.  Based on the wattage of replacement coils:
6" elec burner(120v)  1500w = 12.5amps
8" (220v)  2350w =10.68 amps   or 2600w = 11.8amps.
I thought I was saving $ by using the small burner all these years.
Can someone else confirm this?

Comment: Your electricity is billed by watts, not by amps, so if you have a 240v appliance pulling 5 amps, it's billed the same as a 120v appliance that pulls 10 amps.

Comment: What is the model number?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are mistaken about your assumption that there is a difference in voltage on different size coils on an electric range top. The switches, wiring harness and sockets are the same for all the range top coils. there is no difference in voltage and all feeds are interchangeable except for the length of the wire feed that helps keep the orientation correct. If you buy a replacement socket, it has long leads and you need to cut them to length.  The only difference is for "canning elements" which are 8 inch more highly concentrated coils that exceed the wattage rating of the normal coils and require a special higher rated switch.

Comment: Thanks shirlock. I remeasured the voltage to the burners by tipping up the cooktop surface(instead of plugging the probes into the burner slots) which gave me better access to the wire connections. It was 220v to the small burner.
My bad...

Answer (score 0):

I would say neither is significantly more efficient than the other assuming that you are getting the same rate of heat transfer between the coil and your pan.  A watt is simply a measure of energy transfer (one joule per second), so your electrical feed transfers energy more slowly through the smaller element if it has a lower wattage. The burners don't *increase* the amount of energy at all - they convert it into thermal energy that is then transferred to whatever is sitting on the burner.  Unless the way the pan contacts the burner is less efficient (for example the pan is smaller than the burner), you will use roughly the same amount of energy to perform the same amount of heating. The only difference will be speed - larger elements take longer to heat up with the same wattage, but they have more surface area for heat transfer.